Lemma 9, Section 5.2 of Hungerford’s Algebra

Let $F$ be an extension field of $K$ and let $H,J$ be subgroups of the Galois group $\text{Aut}_K F$ with $H\lt J$. If $[J : H]$ is finite, then $[H': J']\leq [J : H]$.
Proof: Let $[J: H] = n$ and suppose that $[H': J'] > n$. Then there exist $u_1,u_2,…,u_{n+1} \in H'$ that are linearly independent over $J'$. Let $\{\tau_l,\tau_2,…,\tau_n\}$ be a complete set of representatives of the left cosets of $H$ in $J$ (that is, $J = \tau_1H \cup \tau_2H \cup \cdots \cup \tau_nH$ and $\tau_i^{-1}\tau_j\in H$ if and only if $i = j$)
$$\vdots$$
To see this the reader should first verify the following two facts.
(i) For any $\sigma \in J$, $\{\sigma \tau_1,\sigma \tau_2, ... , \sigma \tau_n \}\subset J$ is a complete set of coset representatives of $H$ in $J$.
(ii) if $\xi$ and $\theta$ are both elements in the same coset of $H$ in $J$, then (since $u_i \in H'$) $\xi(u_i)= \theta (u_i)$ for $i= 1,2,...,n+1$.
It follows from (i) that there is some reordering $i_1,…, i_{n+1}$ of $1,2,…,n+1$, so that for each $k = 1,2,...,n+1$ $\sigma \tau_k$ and $\tau_{i_k}$ are in the same coset of $H$ in $J$. By (ii) the $k$th equation of $(2)$ is identical with the $i_k$th equation of $(1)$.

I proved (ii). Let $\xi$ and $\theta$ are in same coset of $H$ in $J$. Then $\xi H=\theta H$. That is $\xi^{-1}\theta\in H$. Since $u_i\in H’$, $\xi^{-1}\theta (u_i)=u_i$. Thus $\xi(u_i)=\theta (u_i)$.
In (i) I proved $\{\sigma \tau_1,\sigma \tau_2, ... , \sigma \tau_n \}$ is mutually disjoint. Since $\tau_iH=\tau_jH \Leftrightarrow i=j$, we have $$\sigma \tau_iH=\sigma \tau_jH \Leftrightarrow \sigma^{-1} \sigma \tau_iH=\sigma^{-1} \sigma \tau_jH \Leftrightarrow \tau_iH=\tau_jH \Leftrightarrow i=j.$$
I can’t show $J=\sigma \tau_1H\cup \cdots \cup \sigma \tau_nH$. Let $\beta \in J$. Then $\beta = \tau_i h_1$ for some $h_1\in H$. Since $\sigma \in J$, we have $\sigma =\tau_j h_2$ for some $h_2\in H$. How to progress from here?
Is it mandatory to show $J=\sigma \tau_1H\cup \cdots \cup \sigma \tau_nH$? I mean $\sigma \tau_1H,…, \sigma \tau_nH$ are $n$ distinct cosets of $H$ in $J$. For each $k = 1,2,...,n+1$,  $\sigma \tau_kH$ must be equal to $\tau_{i_k}H$.

You already know that $H$ has index $n$. You have $n$ distinct cosets of $H$... so that's the complete list of cosets. You must have $J$ equal to the union. (And if you are assuming that $H$ and $J$ are finite... just count how many elements you have!)

@ArturoMagidin Thank you for the answer.
